# Flutter, Firebase Google sign in error - I/flutter ( 5171): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, sha

I have been having issues with signing in to google on a flutter app I am trying to develop. I keep on getting the same error on my debug console which is -

```
I/flutter ( 5171): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

I have updated my SHA-1 and SHA-2 keys on my firebase console, which took me ages to find as the command line commands

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
keytool -list -v -keystore path-to-your-release-key.keystore -alias your-key-alias -storepass your-keystore-password -keypass your-key-password
```

show up with the following errors

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:923)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:423)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:416)
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: path-to-your-release-key.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: path-to-your-release-key.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:923)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:423)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:416)
PS C:\Users\marsd>
```

Im stuck and don't know what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty poor and I also got this problem while generating the jks file. I found a solution though. You'll need to replace the 'path' with an actual path in your device. Something like this.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\WINDOWS\debug-key.jks 
-storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 
-alias androiddebugkey
```

`C:\Users\WINDOWS\` represents the folder's path, while `debug-key` represents the name for the jks file. Meanwhile, `androiddebugkey` is the name of the alias. For the alias, you can name it whatever you want.

After setting up the command properly, the command line will ask for the password, which you are required to fill, and after that private info such as first name, address, etc. You can choose to ignore the latter though by just hitting the enter key.

Once the jks file is generated, make sure to go to the folder you specified in the command then copy it. Paste it in the `android/app` directory in your Flutter project. Then go to `android/app/build.gradle`, update the `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes` section like this.

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyAlias 'the alias you specified'
        keyPassword 'the key password you inserted'
        storeFile file('"name of the file".jks')
        storePassword 'the store password you inserted'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

You need to modify accordingly based on the information you inserted in the command line. Note that this is just for the debug mode. For release mode you will need to repeat the entire step, and replace the `debug {` with `release {`.

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: afraid that is not working, the issue I am getting now is - The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe   

I had to reinstall the jdk to 11 and now it just keeps picking up this old path, it seems to work in android studio but wont work in vs code

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I mean where and when did you get this error? Because out of all the errors I encountered while creating a new jks file I've never seen this error. I just created a new jks file hours ago with that command and it doesn't return any error. Just make sure you supplied the correct path where you wanna place this jks file and make sure you're running this command in the default startup directory of the command prompt and not the directory of your project.

Comment: The issue I had originally was that I had jdk-21 installed, and to get the SHA keys I needed a lower version so I downloaded jdk-11. I managed to get the command ./gradlew signingReport to work in android studio so I could get my SHA keys, but vs code keeps giving me this error - 
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe
I have been down a rabbit hole trying to get the SHA keys and one thing has led to another so apologies for things changing but this is where I am at now.